# arm64 bare-metal application build problem

Tags: c, gcc, printf, arm64, bare-metal

I am using a arm cortex-a55 based MPU and use the toolchain gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf.tar from 'developer.arm.com'. I just want to build a simple bare-metal application and will use freertos multi-task environment later.

In the Makefile:

set CC=/opt/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-gcc

c source compile options:

$CC  -mcpu=cortex-a55 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-stack-protector -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections

linking options:

$CC -Wl,--gc-sections -nostartfiles -T,link.lds -Wl,-Map,System.map

I write my own startup.S with _start entry point. It simply does data section relocation and bss clear, sp setup and bl to main().

```
int main()
{

    stdout = fopen("uart", "w");

    printf("Hello, world!\n");

    while(1);

}
```

I also implement the platform depandant fuctions:

```
int _open(const char *pname, int flags){

    uart_init();

    return 1;
}

ssize_t _write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count){

    char *str = (char *)buf;

    uart_print(str);

    return (ssize_t)count;
}

void * _sbrk(ptrdiff_t incr)
{
        static char *heap = NULL;
        char *prev_heap;

        if(NULL == heap)
                heap = (char *)asm_get_heap_start();

        prev_heap = heap;

        heap += incr;

        /* total 1KB heap area */
        if((u64)heap > asm_get_heap_end())
        {
                errno = -ENOMEM;
                return NULL;
        }

        return (void *)prev_heap;
}
```

and others like _read(), _lseek()...

After compile and link, download the raw binary to board and run. Nothing output. After debug I find the cpu hangs inside fopen(). If I replace fopen() with uart_init(), it will hang inside printf().

I am sure the uart_init() and uart_print() are OK. Because if I don't use fopen() and printf(), and use uart_init() and uart_print() directly, it works fine.

I am not sure if I miss some macro(s) needed for .c source file. There are lots of macros in the newlib/libc/include header files. Or something need to be done before 'printf()'.

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: please format your post properly

Comment: My gut feeling would be floating-point stuff.

Comment: @Siguza Thanks. I disable floating point exception first, but in vain. I think it's caused by NULL pointer from some data structure. But I don't know what I shoud do before printf().

Comment: `fopen` and `printf` cause allocations in most `libc` implementations. Could you provide your implementation of `sbrk`?

Comment: @HarryMock I edited the post and add the _sbrk(). I've checked the -ENOMEM case, and found the case is not matched(entered).